# Storing a session and loading it to a list in VB / ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an Access Database that has a list of points I want to generate that have an attached ID. This ID I use on the Homepage. But I want to store the list of points (As Double) to be used later on to generate a chart.

Comment: I presume by "session" you probably mean an "ASP.Net web session".  Here's a good tutorial: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/.

Comment: I mean Session variable. So I'm storing that variable into another page

Comment: So if you're "storing to another page" - real easy: just declare an array(), and save your points array to the session.  Each page that shares the session can read or write the array.